# How to mock a queryset passed as an argument in python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I need to create a testcase for below function. a queryset is passed as an argument in function. I have to mock that for filter.How to do that

```
def get_weekly_user_data(req_date, data, weeks, mail_attachments):
    for date_length in range(1, len(req_date)):
        weeks.append('week' + str(date_length))
        date1 = req_date[date_length - 1]
        date2 = req_date[date_length]
        data.append(mail_attachments.filter(resolved_at__date__gt=date1,      resolved_at__date__lte=date2).count())
    return data, weeks
```

tried this.but not working.I need to give some dynamic input as date and and filter those queryset using input

```
class TestGetSomeData(unittest.TestCase):
   
    def test_get_weekly_user_data_positive(self):
        # Create a list of Mocked MailAttachment instances
        mail_attachments = [
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 5)),
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 7)),
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 9)),
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 12)),
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 16)),
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 19)),
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 21)),
            mock_mail_attachment(resolved_at=date(2023, 8, 23))
        ]

        req_date = ['2023-08-01', '2023-08-08', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-22']
        data = []
        weeks = []

        # Mock the queryset of MailAttachment
        mock_queryset = Mock()
        
        # Define behavior for filter method based on input dates
        mock_queryset.filter.side_effect = [
            mail_attachments[0:2],  # Attachments for week 1
            mail_attachments[2:5],  # Attachments for week 2
            mail_attachments[5:8]   # Attachments for week 3
        ]
        
        mock_mail_attachment.objects.all.return_value = mock_queryset

        # Call the function with the mocked MailAttachment queryset
        actual_data, actual_weeks = get_weekly_user_data(req_date, data, weeks, mock_mail_attachment.objects.all())

        # Define the expected results
        expected_data = [2, 3, 3]  # Adjusted based on the mocked data
        expected_weeks = ['week1', 'week2', 'week3']

        # Assert the results
        self.assertEqual(actual_data, expected_data)
        self.assertEqual(actual_weeks, expected_weeks)
```